# Are the Spartan-IVs depicted in the Halo 5 opening cinematic true to the previous lore?

Tags: halo

In this intro cinematic to Halo 5 a team of 4 Spartan-IVs, part of Fireteam Osiris, are seen skydiving, jumping and running down a mountain and wiping out a bunch of Covenant and Prometheans along the way.

The trailer is unusually fast paced for a Halo cinematic, with all the characters quickly navigating their way down the mountain while simultaneously wiping out the enemy forces with ease.

I have seen a lot of controversy online to this trailer where some people have said the depictions of the Spartans in this trailer are true to the books (of which I have only read 2 books), while some have argued that the combat seems like something out of an Avengers movie and that the combat skills shown here are very much out of place.

Are the depictions of Spartan IVs Buck, Vale, Locke, and Tanaka in the Halo 5 opening cinematic true to the lore?

Comment: You might want to define the scope of what you consider "the lore" to be.  This is the official opening cinematic of one of the core *Halo* games, so in one sense, it is by definition a part of the *Halo* lore.

Comment: Lore is what the games have shown of the Spartans, what the books have shown, movies, etc. Anything done by the developers or others that have been canon to the storyline

Comment: That's what I mean: this video *is* done by the developers.  It is canon, it is a part of the lore.  If there's a difference in these Spartans' abilities, it will likely be a part of the plot of *Halo 5*, just like the evolving capabilities of the Iron Man suit are detailed in the *Iron Man* movies.  We won't know until it's out, but one thing's for sure: nothing in this cinematic goes against canon, because it *is* canon.

Comment: Perhaps you should ask if this is accurate according to PREVIOUS canon/lore. As Nerrolken stated, if it's depicted in a core HALO game, it essentially becomes canon regardless of what we as fans think. If HALO 7 depicts the Spartans wearing pink rubber suits covered in polka-dots & using spoons as their primary weapon, that would then be canon.

Comment: @Omegacron Fair point, revising.